# How to use plain text and variables in the same Println statement (JAVA)

Tags: java

How is it possible? I have tried:

```
System.out.println("Your answer is: " + answer);
```

and

```
System.out.println("Your answer is: ", answer);
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Your first code snippet seems fine.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You would have found that

```
System.out.println("Your answer is: " + answer);
```

Works! :)

Comment: And some one downvoted me for this :) .. lol

Comment: You answered the only answer they knew... lol

Comment: @dj anyhow OP wants answer :)

Answer (score 2):

The first line of code is fine as you are concatenating the string and outputting it.

But the second line will not be valid (If your indented result, is the same as the first one), you are passing the name string object as  a parameter to the println method. You could use something like `String.format` that will allow you to use printf style string (If I can call it that ... ) .

Example:

```
String.format("Blah %d Blah", i)
```

so in your example:

```
System.out.println(String.format("Your answer is: %s", answer));
```

**Haven't tested this code, wrote it of the top of my head.**

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.println("Your answer is: " + answer);
```

if you are asking how is it possible,

its because of **answer** objects `toString()` method. as we know `println()` takes String and when its sees a string at first, it calls `toString()` method of next variable/Object and make it a String. If that is `int` value it does `AutoBoxing` and converts it into `Integer()` object and calls its `toString()` method

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.println("Your answer is: " + answer);` should work.

Note that if `answer` points to an object (i.e. is not a primitive), the  `toString()` method is implicitly called. <strike>Primitives are just converted to their string representation.</strike> Primitives are wrapped by a corresponding wrapper class (see my comment below), on which `toString()` is invoked. Still, you don't have to worry about that in the case of primitives, since the wrappers override `toString()` in way that one expects (having a primitive `int i = 100` would result in `100` being printed).

For `String` objects that returns the string itself, but for arbitrary objects that might just be the class name and the memory address.

Example:

```
mypackage.Answer answer = new mypackage.Answer("yes"); 
System.out.println("Your answer is: " + answer);
```

This might just print the following if `Answer` doesn't override `toString()`:

```
 Your answer is: mypackage.Answer@15ff48b
```

Overriding `toString()` like this:

```
class Answer {
  private String text;

   Answer(String t) {
     text = t;
   }

  public String toString() {
    return text;
  }
}
```

Would then result in:

```
Your answer is: yes
```

Comment: it works well with primitives too... AutoBoxing:)

Comment: @ntc AFAIK autoboxing isn't involved with `"number is " + 1` for example. In that case the + operator would just convert 1 to a string without doing `new Integer(1).toString()`.

Comment: let me ask it as question then... but till then i'll agree wiyh you

Comment: @ntc I just looked up the [spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#39990) and it proves me wrong :) `If T is byte, short, or int, then use new Integer(x). `

Comment: yeah.... there is now way it int can be converted to String without Wrapper class

Comment: @ntc well you could do `String.valueOf(i)` instead, which calls `Integer.toString( i, 10)` (for `int i` of course :) ) - so no need to actually create a wrapper object.

Comment: @Thomas..sure Thomas..people gave me better solution. just have look at my recent question..

Comment: @ntc I looked at your question and yes, there are the overloaded `print()` methods. As for `print("my number" + i)`: it is the method taking a string argument, but just before the string concatenation happens, which converts `i` to a string (and that's where the spec comes into play).